# On the defense of "change from baseline" even in randomized trials - can anyone question points in this article?

Tags: regression, panel-data, ancova, pre-post-comparison

Many times I read a strong criticism on the change-from-baseline (adjusted for baseline or not) both in randomized and non-randomized. Several people advised "don't even think of reporting the change scores and do the ANCOVA on post values", because of: 1) regression to the mean, 2) being unreliable, 3) being biased, 4) being inappropriate, 5) "change from baseline is not a measure of effect" and many more.

Especially Professor Frank Harrell often questions this approach, e.g. in his "Biostatistics for Medical Research": http://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf

/ There was also an argument about ordinal data, but I will ignore it in this discussion, focusing only on numerical target variables. /

Yet today I found this long article summarizing a lot of literature with rich citation, which questions all of the above arguments and defends the change score: https://homes.ori.org/keiths/Tips/Stats_GainScores.html

I disagree with one thing, that change score and post-ANCOVA will give always equivalent results in RCTs - it's very easy to provide two examples:

- statistically significant change at baseline and post-treatment. The change score will be similar in both groups (parallel lines), but the post ANCOVA will show effect. It's natural, as the statistically significant change at baseline is nothing but an artefact, which has to be ignored due to randomization. So the change score is invalid procedure here.
- statistically significant change at baseline and no change post treatment. The change score will show big difference (converging lines, like an arrow), while post ANCOVA will show no difference. Again, due to randomization post ANCOVA is right, and change score is invalid.

But apart from the two issues, could anyone refer to the other arguments and tell, if the change score is actually a valid approach?

It cannot be, that one questions some approach totally, while many others say "no, it's not true, you can use it". Mathematics is not about a "concenus", it's about facts.